# Any documentation for audio_common_msgs/AudioData.msg

Tags: ros, audio, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any detailed documentation for **audio_common_msgs/AudioData.msg**?

I need information for example:

- What is the **layout** for these data?
- How many **channels** are there?
- What is the **data format** (U8 OR S16_LE)?
- I assume one message is one data frame. Then, how many **samples** are **in one frame**?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98741/any-documentation-for-audio_common_msgs/audiodata.msg/) by [hwp](https://answers.ros.org/users/8546/hwp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, these messages are missing the equivalent of a "camera_info" topic to describe the data (there was at one point a discussion about fixing this, but there are very few people doing audio in ROS right now).

The message itself doesn't constrain you to a particular set of parameters -- however, if you want to use the tools in the audio_common stack, then that sets the parameters. For instance, the [audio_capture node](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/hydro-devel/audio_capture/src/audio_capture.cpp) will encode the data as 192kbit/s MP3, the number of samples per message is variable I believe.

For the most part, people only use these messages with the audio_capture/audio_play nodes, and so it hasn't been much of a problem. If you are uninterested in using either of these nodes, you can actually put any form of data into the message, although it may be wiser to just create a new message type for your particular application.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2